# TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automation

I got this error and I have changed the element to css, id and the error still exist

```
chekboxes = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']")
print(len(chekboxes))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `find_element_by_xpath` (used for search for single element) with `find_elements_by_xpath` (used for search for list of elements)